Rsyslog Client hello message showing Too many ciphers when used tls connection
I have configured rsyslog over tls. My client hello message sending too many ciphers:
Tried using debian machines and Redhat 8 Machines both resulted in same way.
rsyslog version: 8.2404 gnutls - 3.7.1
Server config:
$DefaultNetstreamDriver gtls
$DefaultNetstreamDriverCAFile /etc/rsyslog-keys/ca.pem
$DefaultNetstreamDriverCertFile /etc/rsyslog-keys/server-cert.pem
$DefaultNetstreamDriverKeyFile /etc/rsyslog-keys/server-key.pem

$ModLoad imtcp  
$InputTCPServerStreamDriverMode 1  
$InputTCPServerStreamDriverAuthMode anon
$InputTCPServerRun 6514  

Client config:
$DefaultNetstreamDriverCAFile /etc/pki/tls/private/ca.pem
$DefaultNetstreamDriverCertFile /etc/pki/tls/private/client-cert.pem
$DefaultNetstreamDriverKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/client-key.pem
$DefaultNetStreamDriver gtls

$ActionSendStreamDriverMode 1   
$ActionSendStreamDriverAuthMode anon

*.*     @@<ip>:6514

Exposing 31 cipher suites, even when many config changes done.
How to limit those ciphers to desired numbers?
Below is the wireshark showing 31 ciphersuites for tls client hellohandshake:

Tried many ways by updating rsyslog config, Gnutlsprioritystring etc  nothing worked.

Regarding RHEL 8, your question might be "How to disable specific crypto algorithms when using system-wide cryptographic policies?", maybe you'll need to search for an answer to that. See in example: https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/configuring-rhel-8-compliance-crypto-policy-related-cipher-block-chaining and https://access.redhat.com/articles/7041246.

Despite of that, your topic is not programming at all but configuration only. Therefore you should try on unix.stackexchange.com, serverfault.com, superuser.com, etc. ...
